# Does the term "page responsible" make any sense in English?

Tags: terminology, internet

Each page on my organizations web site is assigned a person that takes responsibility for the content of that page.

E.g. in the page footer

```
Page Responsible: John Doe
```

The current term used to denote this person is "Page Responsible" which does not sound like something you can say in English.

English however, is not my native tongue. Therefore, I ask you English Language & Usage, does the term "Page Responsible" sound ok to you? Or should something else be used, e.g.

- Responsible for page content: John Doe
- Responsibility for page content: John Doe
- Page owner: John Doe

Comment: Page owner sounds the best in my opinion

Comment: Why not just "Footer: John Doe", "Index: Jane Smith", etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a native speaker, and it doesn't sound okay to me.  Although I don't think it's completely incomprehensible, it certainly takes some work to figure out what that string of words means.

To me, *page responsible* sounds like it's elliptical for "page [that is] responsible [for something]".  But the **page** isn't responsible for anything; a **person** is, so that interpretation doesn't make sense.  And since that doesn't work, I'm left guessing at what the relationship between the two words is.

Of your choices, *page owner* seems to fit best to me.  Failing that, all the choices that come to mind are longer--*person responsible for content on this page*, for example.  Your other options look fine, too.  But personally, I'd stick with *page owner*, since it's concise and just as easily understood.

Comment: But you can say [shopowner](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shopowner#Noun), [car owner](https://www.carveto.co.uk/car-history-check/car-previous-owners/), and [homeowner](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homeowner#Noun) (?)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the term "focal" (short for "focal point") used for this purpose in recent years. If that's a bit trendy, "owner" would be a more traditional noun, in the sense that the person "owns" the responsibility for the content.

Answer (score -1):

What about

> - Page Master
> - Page Manager
> - Page Director
> - Page Wrangler
> - Page Shepherd
> - Page Guru
> - Page Chief
> - Page Maven
> - Page Holder
> - Page Warden
> - Page Handler
> - Page Coach
> - Page Leader
> - Page Czar
> - Page Prince